# Can actions be one-off orlast for a period? Is it correct to say "He hid behind the door a few minutes ago and now he is hiding behind the door"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, phrase-usage

Let's say, a light is now in its off-state (not operating) and then I pressed the switch and I say "**I turned on the light**"

And now the light is in its on-state (operating) and we say "**The light is on now**".

So, for the verb "**to turn on the light**", we have an adjective "**on**" to express its state.

Do we say "**I closed my eyes 1 minute ago and now you don't see them because they are closed**" or "**I closed my eyes 1 minute ago and now you don't see them because I am closing my eyes**"?

Do we say "**I covered my face with a blanket 1 minute ago and now you don't see it because it is under the blanket**" or "**I covered my face with a blanket 1 minute ago and now you don't see it because I am covering it with a blanket**"?

Do we say "**He hid behind the door a few minutes ago now you don't see him because he is hiding behind the door**" or "**He hid behind the door a few minutes ago and now you don't see him because he is behind the door**"?

But some verbs can be both one-off and state.

For example, "**I saw her a few minutes ago and now I see her**". We don't need a completely different structure to express the state of "**see**".

or, "**I kissed her 1 minute ago and now I am kissing her**"

or, "**I listened to the song 1 minute ago and now I am listening to the song**"

or, "**I lay in bed 1 minute ago and now I am lying in bed**"

Comment: None of the last four examples are idiomatic (even though they are grammatical). (1) *I saw her a few minutes ago, and now I see her **again**.* (2) *I **started to kiss** her 1 minute ago, and I am **still** kissing her.*

Comment: "I closed my eyes a minute ago and they are still closed." "I covered my face with a blanket and it is still hidden/covered." "He hid behind the door and he is still behind it." Your versions are unnecessarily complicated and explicit.

Comment: Actions (i.e, non-states) are complicated. There are several varieties, which work in different ways grammatically. An action can be **_Punctual_**, like kicking or stamping, which take place in a moment, or it can be **_Durative_**, like riding or singing. The difference there is one of time. But actions can be composed as well; there are plain **_Acts_**, like climbing, **_Achievements_**, which are punctual, like arriving at the summit, and **_Accomplishments_**, which are a combination of an act with its termination in an achievement, like climbing a mountain. The terms are due to Vendler.

Comment: When you say "I saw her a few minutes ago and now I see her.", it is not the same as your other examples. You would have to say "I was kissing her 1 minute ago and now I am kissing her.". Saying "I kissed her" would be like saying "I seen her", in a way. Also, it's weird because you're talking about the same thing unnecessarily. If you were to say "I kissed her yesterday and now I am kissing her friend." or "I listened to the song 1 minute ago and I am now listening to her talk." it would make more sense.